# Time complexity of convex quadratic programming when the number of constraints is much greater than the number of variables

Tags: convex-optimization, quadratic-programming

I have a problem with the format:
$$
\text{minimize   } x^TPx+c^Tx \\
\text{subject to  } Gx\leq b
$$
where P is a positive definite matrix. In my case, $G$ is a $m\times n$ matrix and $m$ is much greater than $n$, which means the number of constraints is much greater than the number of variables. According to the literature I have found, time complexity relates to the number of variables, but I think it is not the case in my problem.

My question is: how to analyze the time complexity of this problem. I will appreciate it if you can recommend some related references.
Thank you.